# How to compare two large existing text files T1 and T2 with more than 2000 lines, line by line in c# .net?

Tags: c#, .net

Am trying to compare two text files T1(New) and T2(Old) line by line, each with 2000 lines  and print the new line added or removed in textfile T1(New) compared to T2(Old) and print the difference in lines or the result on the console or to the new text file. I need help.
Thank you

Comment: There are duplicate answers already and the problem itself isn't that hard - simply reading the lines from each fie one by one in a loop would work. And 2K lines ins't large

Comment: it does actually. If you think it doesn't you didn't ask your actual question. What did you try, what was your problem with what you tried? Did you search SO for similar questions? **Why** can't you use them?

Comment: Read [ask] and [edit] your question to explain why not. Plenty of duplicates exist, show what you have tried.

Comment: i tried this concept which is explained here , but during compilation its giving an unhandled exception and closing the console.

Comment: What exception? Post it here. `Enumerable.Except` works. Reading lines works. If you used the *wrong* file path withouth any error handling you'd get an unhandled exception. You still haven't explained what you tried or what the problem is with what you tried. Why don't you use a simple loop?

Comment: Sir, i resolved that exception because i had forgot to include "using System.Collections.Generic;". But while printin the result this is what am getting "System.Linq.Enumearble+<ExceptIterator>d.__1`1[System.String].

Comment: Sir Am using the Correct paths for both files but struggling to print the difference from text file. please help

Comment: @Naim because you tried to type the IEnumerable, not its contents. Perhaps you should start with a C# tutorial before looking to compute file differences

Comment: Sir am a beginner that is why am facing problem. For sure i will go through c# tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
String directory = @"C:\Whatever\";
String[] linesA = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, "FileA-Database.txt"));
String[] linesB = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, "FileB-Database.txt"));

IEnumerable<String> onlyB = linesB.Except(linesA);

File.WriteAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, "Result.txt"), onlyB);
```

Comment: This doesn't account for order.

Comment: @CodeCaster but he said line by line which implies its ordered

Comment: If you have a file with lines `A, B, C` and a file with lines `C, A, B` this code will report no differences. "Line by line" does not imply ordered files. You should either mention this caveat in your answer, or post a comment asking for clarification before answering. Comparing files is not as trivial as you make it seem.